# php not working correctly on the enquiry/callback form but works fine on the contact form

Tags: php, html

This is confusing me any ideas as to why I only receive the telephone number (missing the name and email fields) when a form is submitted? Ive tried changing everything but i can't seem to get the other 2 fields to work when submitted.

```html
  <aside class="sidebar">
    <h3 class="text-center">Request a Callback</h3>

    <div class="enquiry-wrapper">
      <form id="enquiry-form" method="post" action="enquiry.php" class="clearfix">
        <input type="text" name="enquiry-name" id="enquiry-name" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Name ...">

        <input type="email" name="enquiry-email" id="enquiry-email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email ...">

        <input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Phone Number ...">

        <div class="form-submit">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-colour" name="enquiry-submit" id="enquiry-submit" value="Send message">
        </div>
        <!-- form-submit end -->
      </form>
      <div id="enquiry-message"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- enquiry-wrapper end -->
  </aside>
```

This is the enquiry.php

```js
    <?php
/*
 *  CONFIGURE EVERYTHING HERE
 */

// an email address that will be in the From field of the email.
$from = 'contact@rpsfm.co.uk';

// an email address that will receive the email with the output of the form
$sendTo = 'contact@rpsfm.co.uk';

// subject of the email
$subject = 'new contact form';

// form field names and their translations.
// array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$fields = array('enquiry-name' => 'Name', 'enquiry-email' => 'Email', 'tel' => 'Tel');

// message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
$okMessage = header( 'Location: http://rpsfm.co.uk/thanks1.html' );

// If something goes wrong, we will display this message.
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

/*
 *  LET'S DO THE SENDING
 */

// if you are not debugging and don't need error reporting, turn this off by error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try
{

    if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');

    $emailText = "You have a new message from your contact form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    // All the neccessary headers for the email.
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );

    // Send email
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}


// if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
// else just display the message
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
?>
```

This is the js.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    $("#enquiry-form").submit(function() {
        var e = $(this).attr("action");
        $("#enquiry-message").slideUp(750, function() {
            $("#enquiry-message").hide();
            $("#enquiry-submit").after("").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $.post(e, {
                name: $("#enquiry-name").val(),
                email: $("#enquiry-email").val(),
                tel: $("#tel").val()
            }, function(e) {
                document.getElementById("enquiry-message").innerHTML = e;
                $("#enquiry-message").slideDown("slow");
                $("#enquiry-form img.loader").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                    $(this).remove()
                });
                $("#enquiry-submit").removeAttr("disabled");
                if (e.match("success") != null)
                    $("#enquiry-form").slideUp("slow")
            })
        });
        return false
    })
});
```

Hope I've done this right if not let me know any more info you need.

ATB
Luke

Comment: Please reduce the code to a minimum valuable example and provide a clear question. What **exactly** is not working?

Comment: Are those two forms above on different pages? And what do you mean it doesn't work? Any errors? I'll post my classic message for newcomers to the site.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but *you need to help yourself first*. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't** working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Tried the code you published, worked for me, E-Mail text is as desired.

Comment: @adpro apologies for the confusion I've now edited the question and code. ATB Luke

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple things which make me wonder, besides that I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish.

In enquiry.php:

```
// message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
$okMessage = header( 'Location: http://rpsfm.co.uk/thanks1.html' );
```

Taken this excerp from the manual:

> The second special case is the "Location:" header. Not only does it
>   send this header back to the browser, but it also returns a REDIRECT
>   (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or a 3xx status code
>   has already been set.

By passing this to a variable you are redirecting almost instantly before executing your code.

Secondly your JavaScript code does not seem to work as you desire. I think you want to send your form via AJAX, but your code is ignored, because the form is send via regular post.

`event.preventDefault();` should prevent the sending of the form via regular submit.

Used like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    $("#enquiry-form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // [...]

    });
});
```

I update as I come along with more issues.

**Update**

Please take a look at this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    $("#enquiry-form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var e = $(this).attr("action");
        $("#enquiry-message").slideDown(750, function() {
            $("#enquiry-message").hide();
            $("#enquiry-submit").after("").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $.post(e, {
                "enquiry-name": $("#enquiry-name").val(),
                "enquiry-email": $("#enquiry-email").val(),
                "tel": $("#tel").val()
            }, function(e) {
                document.getElementById("enquiry-message").innerHTML = e;
                $("#enquiry-message").slideDown("slow");
                $("#enquiry-form img.loader").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
                $("#enquiry-submit").removeAttr("disabled");

                if (e.type === "success") {
                    $("#enquiry-form").slideUp("slow");
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

You have used the wrong variable names for the POST data. So your assoc array in the enquiry.php could not use the correct keys and left it out. It seems like the assignment of the header() function works, but it seems like very bad practice to me. You could return the ok message with your AJAX return call, instead of using the header() function.

Comment: Thanks this worked! The whole thing was trail and error.  I’ve taken your advise and changed the headers part. ATB Luke

Comment: @LukeCarty Great that you solved the Problem. Please consider accepting my answer or voting it up.